# how to change making same data-link="n" for all div slides content or completely remove data-link="n" option from <div class="gallery-slide"

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Here is a JS CSS slider that is working correctly but i need to make a little change to this slider.

that is in my slider i want to remove all `data-link="n"` option from `<div class="gallery-slide" ...> </div>` or Make same `data-link="n"` for all div slides classes

at this time my slider HTML structure is like that

```
    <!--slide 1-->
          <div class="gallery-slide" data-link="1">

        <div class="slide-content">
          <h2>Slide 1 Title Here</h2>
          <p>Paragrapgh 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dui nisi,
          lesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
       
        </div>
      </div>
     
     
     <!--slide 2-->
      <div class="gallery-slide" data-link="2">
     
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h2>Slide 2 Title Here</h2>
          <p>Paragrapgh 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dui nisi,
          lesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    
    
    <!--slide 3-->
      <div class="gallery-slide" data-link="3">
      
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h2>Slide 3 Title Here</h2>
          <p>Paragrapgh 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dui nisi,
          lesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
     
     
     <!--slide 4-->
      <div class="gallery-slide" data-link="4">
     
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h2>Slide 4 Title Here</h2>
          <p>Paragrapgh 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dui nisi,
          lesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        
        </div>
      </div>
```

But i want to remove all **`<... data-link="n">`** option from my HTML Structure ,

just like many JS CSS slider have this feature :
for ex. https://codepen.io/MrsColombo/pen/jqxVBg?editors=1010 (this slider's all slides have same class but still working fine.)

**Like from**

```
<div class="gallery-slide" data-link="1">
.....
 </div>
<div class="gallery-slide" data-link="2">
.....
 </div>
<div class="gallery-slide" data-link="3">
.....
 </div>
<div class="gallery-slide" data-link="4">
.....
 </div>
```

**To want change like this**

```
<div class="gallery-slide">
.....
 </div>
<div class="gallery-slide">
.....
 </div>
<div class="gallery-slide">
.....
 </div>
<div class="gallery-slide">
.....
 </div>
```

is it possible ?

plz make it solve

***my Complete Slider Code is here:***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
  <style>
    .gallery {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      padding: 2em 0;
    }

    .gallery-slides {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 1280px;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .gallery-slide {
      position: absolute;
      height: 100%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      flex-direction: row;
      -webkit-box-align: center;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
      transform: translateX(-100%);
      opacity: 0;
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
      order: 2;
      -webkit-transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: opacity, -webkit-transform;
      transition-property: transform, opacity;
      transition-property: transform, opacity, -webkit-transform;
      -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
      transition-duration: 1s;
      -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
      transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.58, 1);
      /* ease-in-out */
    }

    .gallery-slide.is-active {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
      transform: translateX(0);
      opacity: 1;
      -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
      order: 1;
    }

    .gallery-slide.is-active~* {
      -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
      transform: translateX(100%);
      /* E ~ F an F element preceded by an E element
is-active ~ nextSlide element */
    }

    .gallery-selectors {
      width: 5%;
      height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 2.5%;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      -webkit-box-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-box-align: end;
      align-items: flex-end;
    }

    .gallery-selector {
      border: 1px solid #343434;
      border-radius: 50%;
      padding: 1.2em 1.5em;
      margin-bottom: 0.5em;
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #343434;
      -webkit-transition-property: color;
      transition-property: color;
      -webkit-transition-duration: .3s;
      transition-duration: .3s;
    }

    .gallery-selector:hover {
      background-color: #343434;
      color: #e2e2e2;
    }

    .gallery-selector.is-active {
      background-color: #343434;
      color: #e2e2e2;
    }

    .slide-img {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      flex: 0 0 50%;
    }

    .slide-img img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      border-radius: 5px;
    }

    .slide-content {
      -webkit-box-flex: 0;
      flex: 0 1 50%;
      padding-top: 2em;
      padding-bottom: 2em;
      padding-left: 2em;
      padding-right: 10%;
    }

    .slide-content h2 {
      color: #fff;
      font-size: 2.2em;
      line-height: 1;
      margin-top: 0;
    }

    .slide-content p {
      color: #343434;
      font-size: 1.2em;
      line-height: 1.5em;
    }

    /* Background mapColor */
    .background-teal {
      background-color: #54b3a6;
    }

    .background-red {
      background-color: #e72b1e;
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 960px) {
      .gallery-slide {
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .slide-img {
        padding-left: 2em;
        padding-right: 15%;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
      }

      .slide-content {
        padding-right: 15%;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
      .gallery-selectors {
        width: 100%;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
        flex-direction: row;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
      }

      .gallery-selector {
        padding: 0.5em 0.8em;
        margin-right: 0.5em;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
  <section class="gallery background-teal">
    <button data-btn="prev" class="slider-pagination">Pre.❮</button>
    <button data-btn="next" class="slider-pagination">Next ❯</button>
   
   <div class="gallery-slides">
     
     
     <div class="gallery-slide" data-link="1">
        <!--slide 1-->
       
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h2>Slide 1 Title Here</h2>
          <p>Paragrapgh 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dui nisi,
          lesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
       
        </div>
      </div>
     
     
     <!--slide 2-->
      <div class="gallery-slide" data-link="2">
     
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h2>Slide 2 Title Here</h2>
          <p>Paragrapgh 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dui nisi,
          lesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
    
    
    <!--slide 3-->
      <div class="gallery-slide" data-link="3">
      
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h2>Slide 3 Title Here</h2>
          <p>Paragrapgh 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dui nisi,
          lesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>

        </div>
      </div>
     
     
     <!--slide 4-->
      <div class="gallery-slide" data-link="4">
     
        <div class="slide-content">
          <h2>Slide 4 Title Here</h2>
          <p>Paragrapgh 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
            consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dui nisi,
          lesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.</p>
        
        </div>
      </div>
      
      
      
    </div>
    
    <div class="gallery-selectors" style="display: none;">
      <a href="#" class="gallery-selector" data-link="1">1</a>
      <a href="#" class="gallery-selector" data-link="2">2</a>
      <a href="#" class="gallery-selector" data-link="3">3</a>
      <a href="#" class="gallery-selector" data-link="4">4</a>
    </div>
    
    
  </section>
  <!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js'></script>
  <script>
    //Javascript Module Pattern
    //app.js
    var total_slides = $('.gallery-slides .gallery-slide').length;
    $(document).on('click', '.slider-pagination', function() {
      var btn = $(this).attr('id');
      var current_slide = $('.is-active').attr('data-link');
      if ($(this).attr('data-btn') == 'next') {
        if (current_slide < total_slides) {
          var next_slide = parseInt(current_slide) + parseInt(1);
        } else {
          next_slide = 1;
        }
      } else {
        if (current_slide != 1) {
          var next_slide = parseInt(current_slide) - parseInt(1);
        } else {
          next_slide = total_slides;
        }
      }

      console.log(next_slide);
      $('a[data-link="' + next_slide + '"]').trigger('click');
    });

    var app = function() {
      var defaults = [];
      return {};
    }();

    $(function() {
      // new app.gallery();
      $('.gallery').each(function() {
        $(this).data(new app.gallery(this));
      });
    });

    //myModule
    app.gallery = function($, _, app) {
      var def = function(el, opts) {
        this.$els = {
          'el': $(el)
        };

        this.options = _.extend({
          link: 'data-link'
        }, opts);
        this.controller = this.$els.el.find('[' + this.options.link + ']');
        // this.$gallery = this.$els.el.find('.gallery-slides');
        // this.$slide = this.$els.el.find('.gallery-slide');

        this.states = {
          'active': 'is-active'
        };
        init.call(this);
      };

      var init = function() {
        this.bind();
      };

      def.prototype = {
        bind: function() {
          console.log('gallery loaded');
          var self = this;
          this.setActive(1);
          this.controller.on('click', _.bind(this.slideNext, this));
        },

        slideNext: function(ev) {
          var i = $(ev.currentTarget).attr(this.options.link);
          this.setActive(i);
        },

        setActive: function(index) {
          var self = this;
          this.currentActive = index;

          this.controller.removeClass(this.states.active).filter(function() {
            return $(this).attr(self.options.link) == index;
          }).addClass(self.states.active);
        }
      };
      return def;
    }

    (jQuery, _, app);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in Advance, Love You stackoverflow community experts.

Comment: The code works even if you have more then four slides... providing you remember to add them correctly: did you remember to add `<a href="#" class="gallery-selector" data-link="4">4</a>` in the `<div class="gallery-selectors" style="display: none;">`? (here you can see a demo with six slides: https://jsfiddle.net/dyapuqx1/)

Comment: okay Thank You @secan but can you make this structure change like i require in question, that is removing data-link="n" from all slider

Comment: The entire logic for knowing which slide is the current one, which slide should come next, etc. is based on the value of the `data-link` attribute. If you remove it, you have to fundamentally change your code logic: it would be more creating a brand new slider widget rather than customizing the one you are using.

Comment: i know it would be hard task but i need to change this so plz either Make same data-link="n" for all div slides content or completely remove data-link="n" option from <div class="gallery-slide"

Comment: plz help me @ secan

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Where did you get stuck and why? Please share your attempted solution.

Comment: like check this https://codepen.io/MrsColombo/pen/jqxVBg?editors=1010  i have edits in my question

Comment: That is not what I asked you. I asked you to share _your_ attempt to modify _your_ code as _you_ desire. What you did is just linking someone else's code (which obviously has no relation whatsoever with yours). Please do not expect other people to do your job on your behalf as that is not the aim of this community.

Comment: i know @ secan you are exactly right But, i dont have any backup of the code that i tried to make this change, So i requested to you, my aim is not that you are thinking, i hope you are expert so that can make solve my issue.